# Calculating P(X>x), Using Normal Dist.

Tags: probability, statistics

[image]

What is the prob. that if you take Amount of 4.5 units, your RTime will greater than 7?

So far I made the regression line y= x+2. Next I want to calc. $z = \frac{7-6.5}{\sigma}$. How do I calc. sigma? Note, calculation by computer is fine.

Comment: Is it $1\to 8$ or $1\to 7, 4$

Comment: sorry, the last row was an error, I fixed the picture.

Answer (score 1):

You an estimate it by calculating the standard deviation of the errors about the regression line.